# doesn't 'Android API Version 2.1' have webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-sdk-2.1

My test phone version is Android api 2.1 .
And I want to know webview is operated in api 2.1.
thus, I'm trying to below code, but it doesn't operated.

The Palette(When you could see the activity_main.xml GraphicalLayout) didn't have webview control. but, 4.0 version had it.
So I typed 

in XmlCode, but It is shown message that 'The following classes could not be found:
- webview (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)'

Do you know how to operate webview in api 2.1?

p.s) I tried restart eclipse and project clean.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
<webview android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://google.com");  
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: show LogCat, what is the error you got.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The layout XML is case-sensitive. The correct XML you should be using is like this:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I fixed that. But, I can't see control in graphical Layout Palette Compisite in eclipse. Do you know he reason? I'm using Eclipse juno SDK Version: 4.2.0.

Comment: @user2080447, Perhaps you should ask that in a different question. I don't really use the graphical layout at all, so I don't know. But if it works, and my answer helped you, then you could select it as accepted answer (with the checkmark). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) say that WebView has been available since API 1.

You probably have some other problem - the APIs have supported this since the beginning.